# How to change the field's type in mysql?

Tags: mysql

There are 33 fields in `target` table,the type of `report_date` field  is text.

```
select report_date from   target  limit 10;
+--------------+
| report_date  |
+--------------+
| 2015/06      |
| 2016/06      |
| 2017/06      |
| 2018/06      |
| 2019/06      |
| 2014/12      |
| 2015/12      |
| 2016/12      |
| 2017/12      |
| 2018/12      |
+--------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now i want to change  field `report_date`'s type in table `target` from  `text` into `date`.
The record for `report_date` is in the format `2018/12` which contains only year and month, the following MySQL command can't change the field's type as desired.

```
alter table target modify columns  report_date date;
```

And the MySQL command can change only the field `report_date`'s type into my desired.

```
select str_to_date(report_date, '%Y/%m') from target;
```

How can I create a new table `new_target` which alters the field `report_date` in `date` type, and others 32 fields keep unchanged such as in table `target`?

Comment: Do you want to add 01 as the day of month?

Comment: yes,it does not matter,i would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little string manipulation should do together with a create..as select.. - but be careful to rebuild your keys

```
drop table if exists t,t1;

create table t(id int auto_increment primary key, dt varchar(10));

insert into t (dt) values
('2019/01'),('2019/02');

create table t1 as
select id,str_to_date(concat(dt,'/01'),'%Y/%m/%d') dt
from t;

alter table t1 
    modify column id int auto_increment primary key;


select * from t1;

+----+------------+
| id | dt         |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2019-01-01 |
|  2 | 2019-02-01 |
+----+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

To Modify / Alter datatype for Column you need to convert records to full date string first.

Or

You can simple try to get the record with existing data type.

> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(REPLACE(CONCAT(report_date,'/01'),'/','-'),
>   '%Y/%m') as report_date FROM target LIMIT 10;